# Android developpement, Gottox socket.io-java-client: file not fount Exception /socket.io/1/

Tags: java, android, exception, socket.io, handshake

here is my problem:

i've been trying to use [socket.io-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) for an android app but i'm ending up with an handshake error (see below).

here is my app source code:

```
public void runIO(){
    try {
        SocketIO socket = new SocketIO("http://192.168.1.60:1337");
        socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
                System.out.println("an Error occured");
                socketIOException.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection established");
            }

            @Override
            public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
                System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
            }
        });

        // This line is cached until the connection is establisched.
        socket.send("Hello Server!");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and my Node.js / Socket.io:

```
    var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
    var io = require('socket.io')(app); 
    var fs = require('fs');

    app.listen(1337);

    function handler (req, res) {
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
      function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          res.writeHead(500);
          return res.end('Error loading index.html');
        }

        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
      });
    }

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
      socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
```

And i'm getting the following error:

```
    06-09 03:59:53.955: W/System.err(11738): io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking
    06-09 03:59:53.965: W/System.err(11738):    at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:322)
    06-09 03:59:53.965: W/System.err(11738):    at io.socket.IOConnection.access$7(IOConnection.java:292)
    06-09 03:59:53.970: W/System.err(11738):    at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:199)
    06-09 03:59:53.970: W/System.err(11738): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.60:1337/socket.io/1/
    06-09 03:59:53.975: W/System.err(11738):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
    06-09 03:59:53.975: W/System.err(11738):    at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:313)
```

On a browser it works, and the page at `http://192.168.1.60:1337/socket.io/1/` is returning the following message (trough a browser):

```
{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}
```

i don't know what to do to make it work ... please help :x

Thanks :D

EDIT:

As **Larky** said, i had to downgrade my version of Socket.io to *0.9.16*. It worked like a charm with the following node code:

```
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(80); 

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
      socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for asking this question, answer from Larky helps me exactly it helps you, like charm...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem today by reverting to an earlier version of socket.io on the server-side (an earlier version of the socket.io Node module). Perhaps the protocol changed?

To do this:

1. Delete the socket.io folder in your node_modules folder.
2. On the console type:

> npm install socket.io@0.9.16

That should do it... it worked for me :)

(obviously this doesn't completely solve the problem but the earlier version of socket.io worked fine for me for my purposes)

Comment: Thank you, that was it.
Seems like  socket.io-java-client isnt updated for the last version of socket.io.
I wonder if it is still maintained or not. I'm surprise it wasnt updated.

Comment: This is indeed the error that you get when connecting a socketio 0.9 client to a 1.0 server. The handshake changed, so you'll need to either add support to your Java client, or drop back to 0.9 on the server.

Comment: There is a pull request on GitHub that adds 1.0 compatibility, if you want to try. https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/pull/103